# Cannot run ROS2 Humble examples after installing - Windows 10

Tags: ros2

After following the installation tutorial for ROS2 Humble (Windows) [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Windows-Install-Binary.html) I attempted to run the first demo code and got the following error:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME>run demo_nodes_cpp talker
'ros2' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What did I do wrong in the install?

Answer (score 0):

In the install tutorial it states

> In a command shell, set up the ROS 2 environment as described above and then run a C++ `talker`

What this means is that you need to run the following command at the start of every ROS2 session that you have:

```
call C:\dev\ros2_humble\local_setup.bat
```

The command may differ depending on how you set up your installation.

A relatively pain-free way to resolve the issue is to create to do the following:

1. Go to your desktop
2. Right click -> New -> Shortcut
3. Paste the following text as the shortcut: `cmd.exe /K call C:\dev\ros2_humble\local_setup.bat`

This creates a shortcut to the command prompt and auto-runs the environment setup call on opening it.